# Background hides when moving css to css folder?

Tags: css

when my css is located in the root of my website, the background loads fine by adding
    background: url(images/main-bg.jpg) repeat;
into the body, but when i move the css into a folder named "css" and re-link the HREF it seems to disappear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change path to resource `background: url(../images/main-bg.jpg) repeat;`

Comment: Small things hard to notice (=

Answer (score 1):

Are you using relative links correctly? If you're moving that .css file into a folder, the new relative path should be

```
background: url(../images/main-bg.jpg) repeat;
```

...if the images folder is in the root folder as well.

You can use a debugger like Chrome's developer tools or Firebug to double check if the resource is being loaded correctly.

[image: Resource shows up on hover.]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update the CSS. The url is relative to the relationship of the CSS to the image (not the document). Try `background:url(../images/main-bg.jpg) repeat;`

Answer (score 0):

That's because your CSS is now searching for the image in `(root)/css/images/main-bg.jpg`, you need to use a relative path.

```
background: url(../images/main-bg.jpg) repeat;
```

`..` means go back one directory.